# How to combine a PHP variable and $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, variables, request

I am retrieving data from a dynamic form. For that I have counted the number of elements on the form and made each input have a unique name, using the counter variable, eg:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='itemid" . $i . "' value='" . $row['itemid'] . "' />";
```

On the relieving page I need to modify `$_REQUEST[]` to include its own counter variable, eg:

```
while($x <= $counter){

  $itemid = trim($_REQUEST['itemid" . $x . "']);

  $x = $x + 1;

};
```

Does anyone know the correct way of combining the `$_REQUEST` and `$x` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$itemid = trim($_REQUEST['itemid" . $x . "']);
```

should be

```
$itemid = trim($_REQUEST['itemid' . $x]);
```

A better way to do this would be to use arrays. Then you don't need to use a counter to keep track of where you are:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='itemid[]' value='" . $row['itemid'] . "' />";
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['itemid'] as $item) {
    // do stuff
}
```